# How to complete install of bitcoin-0.17.1 on linux (fedora 29)

Tags: bitcoin-core, linux, installation

So I downloaded and unzipped bitcoin core. I now have bitcoin-0.17.1 sitting in my home directory . What next? How do I install and run this? (Obviously I am a newb, help much appreciated.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After extraction files from the tar ball you have to install the contents of its `bin` subdirectory into the `/usr/local/bin` directory using the the `install` command. The install command is part of the GNU coreutils available on nearly every Linux distribution, and the `/usr/local/bin` directory is a standard location for self-installed executables (you may edit the commands below to use a different location).

If you use `sudo` to run commands as root, use the following command line:

```
sudo install -m 0755 -o root -g root -t /usr/local/bin bitcoin-0.14.2/bin/*
```

If you use `su` to run commands as root, use the following command line:

```
su -c 'install -m 0755 -o root -g root -t /usr/local/bin bitcoin-0.14.2/bin/*'
```

See reference [here](https://bitcoin.org/en/full-node#other-linux-distributions)

You can then just run `bitcoin-qt` to startup the GUI

Answer (score -1):

Are you attempting to compile from source or downloaded the linux executables? It is not clear from your original question.

If you downloaded the executables package the first answer references an old version of bitcoin - you'll have to change the references to 0.17.1 (not noob friendly). You can also just cd into the

```
bitcoin-0.17.1/bin
```

directory and run

```
bitcoin-qt
```

or move it wherever you want.

https://www.ringingliberty.com

has a repo and bitcoin packages for Fedora as Fedora does not provide packages directly if you are just looking to run the desktop client.

If you are compiling from source there are other dependencies that must be installed (boost, etc) first.

Beware the bitcoin client (whether gui or server) will consume 221 GiB of storage for the full blockchain as of today and take from days up to a week to sync initially. Research "pruned node" to reduce this to as little as 3.5 GiB.